# MySQL - What does it mean when KEY is added to this create table statement

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE `mynewtable` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `contribId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `pubId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sourceId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` varchar(50) default NULL,
  `content` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `sourceId` (`sourceId`,`date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARSET=latin1;
```

In the above create statement - what does the

```
KEY `sourceId` (`sourceId`,`date`)
```

do/mean for the table?

Comment: KEY is normally a synonym for INDEX. The key attribute PRIMARY KEY can also be specified as just KEY when given in a column definition. This was implemented for compatibility with other database systems. See it here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html

Comment: Oh!? So it creates an index called `sourceId` using `sourceId` and `date`?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it.

Comment: Great! : ) Thanks Jorge Campos - do you think it is a worthy enough question to post your answer for?

Comment: Post the answer, @JorgeCampos =)

Comment: Posted it. Glad that it helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> KEY is normally a synonym for INDEX. The key attribute PRIMARY KEY can also be specified as just KEY when given in a column definition. This was implemented for compatibility with other database systems.

From the MySql docs
See it here: [13.1.14 CREATE TABLE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html)